# Building OpenCV 3.2 with MKL and simd optimization

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, vectorization, intel-mkl

**Disclamer:** I'm not a cmake expert, I used it only to build OpenCV.

Reading [this](http://jamesbowley.co.uk/build-opencv-v3-2-with-cuda-8-0-and-intel-mkltbb/#MKL) it seems that we need to specify that we want to build OpenCV with MKL and simd support.

So do I have to add the following flags?

```
-DENABLE_AVX2=ON -DHAVE_MKL=ON -DMKL_WITH_TBB=ON
```

Digging a little bit on opencv repository in [this](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/55ff28ed93af0c6b4a9eb1399d7c040367f7f4c3/cmake/OpenCVFindMKL.cmake) file it seems we need only to enable ipp (with `-DWITH_IPP=ON` and optionally specify `-DWITH_IPP` if we want to provide our version of IPP).

Am I correct or I'm missing something?